# How to live filter a pre taken video on iOS

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, cifilter

I have a video that I have already taken that I am looping in an AVPlayerLayer. I would like to know the best way to pass that video through a CIFilter for both live filtering and for saving the video with the filter applied. I have found Apple's CIFunHouse to be helpful, but it is for actually taking the video and processing each frame as it is taken where as I want to apply the filter after the video is taken. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at GPUImage: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage